# Output redirect creates file "0"

Tags: bash, redirect, ls

I'm making a ls with a wildcard to check the return code in order to determine if the wildcard matches the files. While this works well, it always creates a file 0 with 0 file size. Does anybody see why?

```
$SSTDIR=/tmp/test
$SSTFILE=test

ls -1 $SSTDIR/$SSTFILE* &> /dev/null
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
    exit 2
fi
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Edit:

```
# Anzahl Parameter überprüfen
if [ ${#} == "6" ]; then
    SST=$1
    IN=$2
    INFILE=$3
    SSTDIR=$4
    SSTFILE=$5
    SORT=$6
else
    echo "Verwendung: $0 \"SST Name\" \"Inbound Verzeichnis ohne /\" \"Name der eingehenden Datei\" \"Outbound Verzeichnis ohne /\" \"Name der ausgehenden Datei\" \"Stelle ab der sortiert wird\""
    exit 3 # Falsche Anzahl Parameter
fi

# Überprüfe ob das eingehende RVS Verzeichnis nicht leer ist
ls -1 $IN/$INFILE* &> /dev/null
if [ $? > 0 ]; then
    exit 1 # Keine Dateien gefunden
fi

# Überprüfe ob das SST Verzeichnis bereits Dateien beinhaltet
ls -1 $SSTDIR/$SSTFILE* &> /dev/null
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
    exit 2 # Dateien existieren bereits im SST Verzeichnis
fi
```

Well that's everything, there's more downwards, but that's not causing the problem, since I've tested the spots with exit.

Comment: This snippet can't work. Give a real example of your code.

Comment: Post updated :) But I don't see why that didn't suffice.

Comment: I hope now you see. :) You give example with wrong variable assignment - `$SSTDIR=/tmp/test`. You shouldn't use `$` with assignment.

Comment: Oh well, I always make that mistake, I'm more used to PHP. As you see, I didn't really cut away something from the code, I just wrote the 2 variables down by hand, instead of copying it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of that `$? > 0`!! The `> 0` is a redirection that creates file `0`! You should be aware that the `[ $? > 0 ]` is not a bash syntactical feature! This is normal commandline call to program named `[`, which is a link to `test` command. Try:

```
$ which [
/usr/bin/[
```

So the "expression" you use there is not an expression, it is normal bash command (with options!). So instead, use `-gt`:

```
if [ $? -gt 0 ] ; then ...
```

Try `man test` to see all the possible options.

Answer (score 1):

Try change to:

```
if [[ $? -gt 0 ]]; then
    exit 1 # Keine Dateien gefunden
fi
```

You should use `>` only with strings and only in special constructions - `((...))` and `[[...]]``.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -1 $IN/$INFILE* &> /dev/null
if [ $? > 0 ]; then
    exit 1 # Keine Dateien gefunden
fi
```

Note the `$? > 0` part.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't see the difference :\

Comment: It is not the difference, i'm just pointing you at the error. `> 0` part redirects the output into the file `0`, just like `>/dev/null` redirects the output into the `/dev/null`.

Comment: Ah, alright then. Well, now that I look at it, it was pretty obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say if it's your problem, but I would normally write it as follows.

```
ls ... >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: I had it like that before, then I tried to change stuff to see if it affects the 0. But thanks :)